# Function to generate cloud of points using a 5 number summary

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy

I want to write a 6 parameter function in python or R that generates a cloud of points based on numbers that summarize the data. The cloud of points generated based on the given information of the 
number of observations, 
average of x-values,
average of y-values,
standard deviation of x-values,
standard deviation of y-values, 
and the correlation coefficient. 
I feel like something like this may exist in python, but if not how would I write something like this? I am familiar with python and just learning R.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html  That will give a single random number from a multivariate normal distribution, put it in a loop to get multiple observations

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `np.random.multivariate_normal` to generate the values, all the other stuff is just converting means and standard deviations into an appropriate covariance matrix

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mean_x = 2
mean_y = 1

std_x = 2
std_y = 5

correlation = 0.7
covariance = correlation * std_y  * std_x

cov = [[std_x**2,covariance],[covariance,std_y**2]]

x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal([mean_x,mean_y], cov, 5000).T
plt.plot(x, y, 'x')
plt.axis('equal')
```

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your question